How to present rooms in a grid style for booking
I am creating a booking style website where students can reserve classes/labs/gyms etc
I feel like my current grid style feels overwhelming. Does there exists a more user friendly way to display this information?
I am adding a filter option above the rooms
Also, i realize that my nav bar is cluttered. I will adjust it later in a differnt layout idea ( feel free to share a better nav bar if you have a better way :) )


Have you checked how other websites like booking.com or airbnb solve this problem?

Contrast
If the distinctive element (images) does not offer sufficient contrast, it must be sought in the design.
Space contrast
Margins
At first glance there is a serious problem regarding margins. In the graph below it is clearly seen how the interior spaces (in red) are exaggeratedly larger than the exterior spaces (in blue). What we try to achieve is that each card perceptually isolates its content. If it is not possible to play with very wide outer margins, there should at least be a balance between the two.


Pay attention to the Gestalt law of proximity, in this case misused, causing confusion in the visual association of elements.

Figure-ground contrast
Framing
Once this balance has been established or generous margins have been achieved, if these margins do not manage to isolate each card, use some graphic resource that emphasizes the "enclosure", such as with a style of frames. In the example, from left to right, drop-shadow, bright contrast, and color contrast:

Layout
Once the "graphics unit" card is created, improve the design and layout. There are thousands of examples on the internet from which to get ideas, for example in dribbble with "UI card design" as a search parameter:

